# converting from classes to Functional component with composition parent-child

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-functional-component

I'm trying to convert React classes with inheritance to a functional component and not miss out on any features. So far I read tons of articles and couldn't figure out how to do that. The main issue is that my parent component modifies the state of a child component.

```
# Base class
class BaseTable extends React.Component {

  // function to filter table when search text is changed
  _onChangeText = (ev, text) => {
    // storing filterText as a state, so onDropdownChange() can refresh filter
    this.setState({ filterText: text });

    if (this.state.items[0] && this.state.items[0].hasOwnProperty(this.state.filterBy)) {
      // refreshing the filteredItems array with new query
      this.setState({
        filteredItems: text ? this.state.items.filter(item => item[this.state.filterBy].toLowerCase().indexOf(text.toLowerCase()) > -1) : this.state.items,
        selectedPageIndex: 0

      });
    }
  };
}

export default BaseTable;
```

Child class that extends it and uses methods of parent class by using `this` reference:

```
class SpecificTable extends BaseTable {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
  }

this.state = {
      items: [],
      filteredItems: [],
      filterText: "",
      selectedPageIndex: 0,
      isError: false,
      errMsg: ''
    };

return (
<TextField
 label="Search Query:"
 onChange={this._onChangeText}
 styles={controlStyles}
 value={this.state.filterText}
 />
);
}

export default SpecificTable;
```

The goal is to convert it to a Functional Component without classes and reuse those functions from BaseTable because I have a few "SpecificTables". I was thinking to create ReactContext but still having issues how would that look like.

Comment: You need to post what you have tried and where you think you are going wrong.

Comment: React explicitly encourages composition over inheritance - i.e. a class component extending from something other than React.Component is an anti-pattern. If you've converting to functional components, it's a good time to get rid of it. You can re-use functions via hooks.

Answer (score 1):

EDIT: Add link to my comment about [composition over inheritance](https://reactjs.org/docs/composition-vs-inheritance.html)

In functional components, you do it by creating a reusable hook that can be used by various table components that previously extended BaseTable

```js
const useBaseTable = () => {

   const [state,setState] = useState(your_base_state);

   const onChangeText = useCallback((arg) => {
      ... your onChangeText
   },[...relevant dependencies]);

   // return your state, setState (if necessary), and your callback 
   // in reality, you can return whatever you want from this hook
   return [state, setState, onChangeText];
}
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer @Adam! Can you expand a little bit more on your answer, to make it even a bit closer to my example?
I read React article about Composition vs Inheritance but still have trouble with managing the Child's state using Parents hooks.